# nullpointer in kieservices.factory.get()

Tags: drools, kie, null-pointer

I am trying to use drools 7 and kie. 
I would like to understand which libraries i need to import for every line of code because probably in production we cant use maven.

Now I import only two libraries: kie-api.7.3 and kie-internal.7.3 and I have a nullpointer  in the first line of code

```
KieServices ks = KieServices.Factory.get();
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: I don't believe that you report the problem correctly. Please show the full stack dump.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But if you can add those .jars, why can't you add all the .jar files that are under the binaries folder inside the .zip that you download from here: https://download.jboss.org/drools/release/7.4.1.Final/droolsjbpm-tools-distribution-7.4.1.Final.zip ?

I just added them all to my project and it is running well in production

Comment: yes it works with all drools jar...but  I would have liked to have control over what jars were really needed to avoid conflicts with other jars in the application

Comment: Take a look at the stack trace, it may be showing which specific jar is missing. If you prefer to add them manually, maybe this is the right approach

@laune I didn't have enough rep to comment... Sorry about that though

Comment: Actually it was more than a comment, but an answer starting with a question doesn't sound right.